# Use a class from a list of generic interface

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement a QueryBus. Basically, I want to register a list of `QueryHandler`s. Each `QueryHandler` implements a `handle` method defined by an interface. Each `QueryHandler` is associated to a `Query`. I want to be able to retrieve a `QueryHandler` using the `Query` and call `handle` on it.

The thing is the handle has to be generic because each `QueryHandler` handles a `Query` differently. They all take a dedicated `Query` and may return whatever they want.

```
interface Query<R>

interface QueryHandler<R, Q : Query<R>> {
    fun handle(query: Q): R
    fun listenTo(): String
}

// DTOs
data class BookDto(val name: String)

// List books query
data class ListBooksQuery(val page: Int = 1): Query<List<BookDto>>

class ListBooksQueryHandler: QueryHandler<List<BookDto>, ListBooksQuery> {
    override fun handle(query: ListBooksQuery): List<BookDto> {
        return listOf(BookDto("Dune"), BookDto("Dune II"))
    }

    override fun listenTo(): String = ListBooksQuery::class.toString()
}

// Get book query
data class GetBookQuery(val name: String): Query<BookDto?>

class GetBookQueryHandler: QueryHandler<BookDto?, GetBookQuery> {
    override fun handle(query: GetBookQuery): BookDto {
        return BookDto("Dune")
    }

    override fun listenTo(): String = GetBookQuery::class.toString()
}

// Run it!

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Initializing query bus
    val queryHandlers = mapOf(
        with(ListBooksQueryHandler()) {this.listenTo() to this},
        with(GetBookQueryHandler()) {this.listenTo() to this}
    )

    val command = ListBooksQuery()
    val result = queryHandlers[command::class.toString()].handle(command)

    // Should print the list of BookDto
    print(result)
}
```

I don't even know if its possible, to be honest.

**UPDATE 1:**
I changed the usage example in the main to show what I am really trying to do. The `List` was for (bad?) demonstration purpose. I want to store the `QueryHandler`s and retrieve them from a map.

**Additional resources:**

Here is what I really want to do: 
https://gist.github.com/ValentinTrinque/76b7a32221884a46e657090b9ee60193

Comment: The QueryBus will be a collection of nested middlewares  (validation, authorization, etc).  Also, the QueryBus will be injected as a dependency in my API controllers. Here is a blog post about Bus pattern (Command in his case) https://matthiasnoback.nl/2015/01/responsibilities-of-the-command-bus/

Comment: Okay, I was not aware of that pattern. I updated my answer.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech Here a very good conference to understand the why such pattern: https://speakerdeck.com/lilobase/ddd-and-cqrs-php-tour-2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** I've read your gist and tried to come up with a solution that will provide a clean interface to the user of the QueryBusMiddleware.
Note that I used objects instead of classes for the QueryHandler implementations, which felt more natural to me (since there is only one possible entry in the map for each Query implementation).

```
interface Query<R>

interface QueryHandler<R, Q: Query<R>> {
    fun handle(query: Q): R
    fun listenTo(): String
}

// DTOs
data class BookDto(val name: String)

// List books query
data class ListBooksQuery(val page: Int = 1): Query<List<BookDto>>

object ListBooksQueryHandler: QueryHandler<List<BookDto>, ListBooksQuery> {
    override fun handle(query: ListBooksQuery): List<BookDto> {
        return listOf(BookDto("Dune"), BookDto("Dune II"))
    }
    override fun listenTo(): String = ListBooksQuery::class.toString()
}

// Get book query
data class GetBookQuery(val name: String): Query<BookDto?>

object GetBookQueryHandler: QueryHandler<BookDto?, GetBookQuery> {
    override fun handle(query: GetBookQuery): BookDto {
        return BookDto("Dune")
    }

    override fun listenTo(): String = GetBookQuery::class.toString()
}

// Run it!
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Initializing query bus

    val queryHandlers = listOf(
            ListBooksQueryHandler,
            GetBookQueryHandler
    )

    val dispatcher: QueryBusMiddleware = QueryDispatcherMiddleware(queryHandlers)

    // Calling query bus
    val query = ListBooksQuery()

    // Result should be List<BookDto>
    val result = dispatcher.dispatch(query)

    print(result)
}

interface QueryBusMiddleware {
    fun <R, Q : Query<R>> dispatch(query: Q): R
}

class QueryDispatcherMiddleware constructor(handlers: List<QueryHandler<*, *>>) : QueryBusMiddleware {
    private val handlers = HashMap<String, QueryHandler<*, *>>()

    init {
        handlers.forEach { handler -> this.handlers[handler.listenTo()] = handler }
    }

    override fun <R, Q : Query<R>> dispatch(query: Q): R {
        val queryClass = query::class.toString()
        val handler = handlers[queryClass] ?: throw Exception("No handler listen to the query: $queryClass")
        return handler::class.members.find { it.name == "handle" }!!.call(handler, query) as R
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your example using a map is exactly what I attempt to do. I've updated the code to show you what I am really trying to build.

Comment: You may want to refine your answer to match the updated code. I may have given you a better context. Maybe ?

Comment: @ValentinTrinqué I've updated my answer. It's derived from your code in the gist. It works and provides a "clean" interface. However, it uses the `!!` operator and an unchecked cast (`as`), so it's up to you to make sure there is an appropriate Handler registered for every possible Query implementation.